# PHP version deprecated

Tags: php

Any ideas for these 2 functions, they stopped working due to PHP version upgrade

```
function read_str($fp)
{
   $strlen = $this->bin2dec(fread($fp, 4), 4);
   return fread($fp, $strlen);
}
```

and

```
function read_byte($fp)
{
  return $this->bin2dec(fread($fp, 1), 1);
}
```

And old script that I am trying to workaround.

Error the server is output

"[22-Feb-2019 20:24:38 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /? on line 2884
[22-Feb-2019 20:24:38 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /? on line 2860
"

Here are the 2 functions

```
    /*!
     * @function read_byte
     * @abstract Reads a byte from a file
     * @param fp  file pointer - pointer to an open file
     * @result the read byte as an int
     */
     function read_byte($fp)
     {
     return $this->bindec(fread($fp, 1), 1);
     }

     /*!
     * @function read_str
     * @abstract Reads a string from a file
     * @param fp  file pointer - pointer to an open file
     * @result the read string
     */
     function read_str($fp)
     {
     $strlen = $this->bindec(fread($fp, 4), 4);
     return fread($fp, $strlen);
     }
```

Here is the actual file been used in which it is calling the error above.

```
    <?php
    if(ereg("[a-zA-Z0-9]",$event))
    {

    //returns highest key in the database
    function getMaxKey($db) {

    $maxKey = 0;

    $sortby = "event_key";
    $result = $db->getall();

    foreach($result as $item){
       $key = $item["event_key"];
       if($key > $maxKey)
          $maxKey = $key;
    }

    return $maxKey;
    }

    // Include the FFDB library
    include("../ffdb.inc.php");

    //open db or create new db
    $db = new FFDB();
    if (!$db->open("../calendar"))
    {
       // Define the database shema.
       // Note that the "last_name" field is our key.
       $schema = array(
          array("_key", FFDB_INT, "key"),
          array("_name", FFDB_STRING),
          array(_year", FFDB_INT)
       );

       // Try and create it...
       if (!$db->create("calendar", $schema))
       {
          echo "Error creating database\n";
          return;
       }
    }

    //if no key file create a new one
    if(!file_exists("key.dat"))
    {
     $newKey = getMaxKey($db);
     $newFile = fopen("key.dat", "w") Or die("Can't open file");
     fwrite($newFile,$newKey);
     fclose($newFile);

    }

    //add a record
    //convert forms to record
     $fileread = fopen("key.dat", "r")Or die("Can't open file");
     $data = (int) fread($fileread, 10);
     fclose($fileread);
     $data++;
     $fileread = fopen("key.dat", "w") Or die("Can't open file");
     fwrite($fileread,$data);
     fclose($fileread);

     //add the record
     $record["_key"] = $data;
     $record["_name"] = ucwords($event);
     list($record["_year"]) = sscanf($year, "%d"); // string -> int

     // Add a _new_ entry
     echo("");
     if (!$db->add($record))
     echo("failed!\n");
     else {

     //table to display after adding
     $addedTable ="
```

Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php

Comment: I have others bind2dec not causing errors, but lets say it is, I will try in a bit. Probably bin2float is gone too? binfloat

Comment: You should show your `bin2dec()` function since your class apparently has a wrapper for PHP's native function.

Comment: None of your custom functions would be deprecated. Unless you let on the concrete error, no one is going to advise anythinig useful.

Comment: Well the bin2dec() page on php.net doesn't exist anymore. http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=bin2dec&lang=en&scope=404quickref

Comment: @RussJ Why do you think that it ever did exist? `bin2dec()` is clearly some custom function of OP's.

Comment: When I googled "php bin2dec", the first hit was a page on php.net.

Comment: @RussJ by that logic [`monkeyzeus_is_da_best()`](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=monkeyzeus_is_da_best&lang=en&scope=404quickref) no longer exists as well...

Comment: For what it's worth, "php  monkeyzeus_is_da_best" doesn't return any results, which is not true for "php bin2dec"

Comment: @RussJ So you're blaming me for your misunderstanding of an improperly indexed Google result of a dynamic page? The **$this** of `$this->bin2dec()` should have been all you needed to know that something is screwy with their custom function; the code of which OP failed to present in their question.

Comment: A 'Strict Standards' message just means you're doing something inadvisable which probably won't have the effect that you think it does, but otherwise isn't terribly serious. This message began appearing since your version upgrade either because a new warning was added for the thing it is warning about, or the upgrade itself changed `error_reporting` to actually show these messages. In any case, the error is most likely due to how that `bin2dec()` method is defined in that class.

Comment: bindec didn't resolve.....editing above

Comment: the error was not showing on previous version, I just found the back file with some errors but not related. All worked before the upgrade and I am unable to downgrade the version even if I want to or need to. Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps the error is not even there, since other functions contain the similar parameters and it is not accusing error. So I am updating the question above and showing the file in which technically the error is happening. This script is very old but it works perfectly for my purposes and wish to keep it on. So any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Sammitch, the error stopped but it is not adding to the >flat< database, I don't get the error, but it returns a blank page and the record it is not added. I just edited above showing the script used to add the record. Any ideas?

Comment: Sammitch, It may be something simple but I already tried all possible aka logical, and still not adding the record. I am using the PHP code checker website and the script is passing with the execption of the EREG function, but tried to change around to PREG then PREG_MATCH but nothing. I am thinking the error is where the //add a record is...tried changing the rights of the dat file and still nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The error is saying already, you are passing $fp which is a fsocketopen probably by open a binary file ... this is forbidden.

The bin2dec is a local custom private function since is called with $this->.